# How to deploy file with sensitive data to heroku? (Rails project with Settingslogic gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, deployment, settingslogic

Im using [Settingslogic](https://github.com/binarylogic/settingslogic) gem as alternative to Environment Variables, and I found it more convenient. But, how to deploy the application to Heroku if my file with configs is out of the repo? I mean, all configs I save in `application.yml`, which is included in `.gitignore` file (because there is sensitive data). And when I push it to heroku, server can't find this file and can't complete deploy.

I've tried to create the file from heroku bash, but after `git push heroku master` command, created file disappears, and deploy failes with the same error.

How can I implement this deploy with one config file, and how can I force heroku to read this file or store it if I have no it in Git? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you really want to be using something with its last commit 6 years ago? The way you would do this in modern versions of rails is by using [encrypted credentials](https://blog.engineyard.com/rails-encrypted-credentials-on-rails-5.2).

Comment: Thank you so much! It is really much more better, and it is work )